# fragment back stack retrieve in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have one activity with drawer in which

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

     mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    .......

    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
    ......
     .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView) {


                    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                    }
                    //return true if we have consumed the event
                    return true;
                }
            })

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();

    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashboardFragment(), TAG);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}

.......

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(){
    //Enable Up button only  if there are entries in the back stack
    boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0;
    if(canback) {
        result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canback);
    }else{
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And in my fragment....

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                folderName = list.get(position).getName();
                //fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, innerFolder, folderName + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, innerFolder, folderName);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(folderName + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getActivity().setTitle(folderName);
```

Now I am trying to pop out each fragment stack name in the activity to set it into title bar when pressed home up button.I need each fragment name that is in stack when pressed hone up button.But I am stuck and unable to do so.. can anyone help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you will be able to get name which you have set in `addToBackStack`

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    Log.e("backstack",""+fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```